# Equity compensation for a foreign worker

Tags: employment, tax-law, salary, visa, equity

Can an employee working from India get equity compensation from the employer who is registered in the USA? The employee does not hold a work visa in the USA and the employer does not have a registered entity in India. If they are allowed to hold equity, then where do they pay taxes - in India or the USA?

Comment: The US does not tax earned income of foreigners who are not physically present in the US.  Capital gains might be another matter; I do not know.  Indian labor law may have something to say about the legitimacy of the arrangement.

Comment: @phoog Thank you. Do you know if the Indian worker is allowed to hold equity in the American company?

Comment: I don't know anything prohibiting it, but I don't know much about Indian law. There's certainly nothing in US law prohibiting it, whether the foreigner is an employee or not.